# Animating SVGs in Edge

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, microsoft-edge

We're moving away from this approach, but I am just trying to find what I was doing wrong.

Here's an SVG I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 792 158.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 158.7;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    @keyframes magglass {
      from {
        transform: translate(-125px, 0);
      }
      to {
        transform: translate(60px, 0);
      }
    }
    #mag-glass-root {
      animation-duration: 6s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-name: magglass;
    }
  </style>
  <g id="mag-glass-root">
   <ellipse class="pink-pig-3" cx="327.5" cy="53" rx="3.5" ry="3"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

In chrome, this moves from left to right. In Edge, it is immobile.

According to [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/supportcsstransformsonsvg/) MS Edge supports CSS transform animations. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should show us the difference in output in Edge and other browsers. You also need to provide an example which we can run on Edge for reproducing the issue may help us to understand the issue in better way. Please provide more information about your issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I am unable to provide the full SVG. I can't imagine that's unusual given how many people work in corporate environment. Apply it to any group in any SVG. 

The difference is that it moves in other browsers, and not in Edge. By 185 pixels,... to the right.

The question really narrows down to two choices that I see:

1- The MS documentation is wrong
2- There's a typo I missed.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, I copied your HTML to a codepen and an HTML file and both worked as expected. I'd suggest testing on another system

Comment: I have gotten this response with a few others that have reported this to me from people running actual Windows machines (i'm on a Mac, and have to use Parallels to access anything Windows). It appears, then, that the problem is with my Parallels version of Edge (whether that's the installation or the implementation I don't care to explore).

Comment: I also tested your code and it worked fine without any issue. As you already found the cause for this issue. I suggest you to post it as an answer as MS Edge don't has this issue while directly using it in Windows. I also suggest you to check MS Edge (Chromium) version which is available for MAC OS. Ref: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/